# Is there a way to silently accept the xcode license?

Tags: xcode, git, macos

I'm trying to automate the installation of git for a large scale deployment on osx, and right now we're relying on the xcode tools version of git. As of OSX Mojave, it now requires the user to accept the xcode license before you can install, which has been breaking all our install scripts. Is there a way to automate the acceptance of this license?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use `xcodebuild -license accept` as root (or with sudo). You may want to use `xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch` instead, which will also install the needed package (you don't need that for git, but it may simplify the rest of your process).